# Problems parsing Hibernate objects containing sets in the Struts2 xslt result type

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, persistence

I am writing an application that utilizes a database with a few many-to-one and one-to-many table relationships.  I used the JBOSS tools in Eclipse to reverse-engineer the database and create the POJOs, and the getters and setters for the foreign-key relationships look something like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
public Set<Layouts> getLayoutses() {
    return this.layoutses;
}

public void setLayoutses(Set<Layouts> layoutses) {
    this.layoutses = layoutses;
}
```

The Sets in these cases are either empty HashSets or HashSets filled with POJOs representing another table in the database.

The problem is that the transform process chokes on the Set property.  I get a `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Error transforming result` message if I leave the FetchType on "LAZY," and if I change it to "EAGER" I get no error message but no response from Struts2 either (the browser just keeps loading forever).  If I change the Set getters to "protected" or "private" instead of "public," everything works without a hitch except, of course, for the fact that the result set will not contain those properties.

Everything I have read seems to indicate that Struts2 should be able to handle the Sets, but the only Struts2/Hibernate integration examples I have been able to find deal with extremely simple data containing no mapped, foreign key relationships.

What do I need to do in order to get the Struts2 xslt result type to play nicely with my Hibernate persistence objects?

Comment: The question needs better partitioning... First prove you are getting all the data you need back.  I don't know much about the xslt result type, is it responsible for serialising the objects for you? If so magical JPA proxy machinery can get in the way. There are still a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I am getting all of the data, aside from the foreign data, since it is on lazy replication.  I'm not sure what you mean by "serializing the objects." A method in the UsersAction class is called by the client POST; UsersAction calls UsersManager, which runs the query and returns a Set of the Users objects. The set is thrown onto the ValueStack, and the Struts2 XSLTResult class turns it into a DomSource object, basically by going through and grabbing all of the exposed variables (all public variables, and/or any variables with public getters).

Comment: Just because the association is lazy does not mean that it should not be fetched before going to the view. So change the query to use a "join fetch" to force the loading, or in your action manually access the lazy collection before sending it to the view (one way is to iterate over the collection). Then send the data to a regular JSP view, if you can see all the data... then let us know. I'm thinking the issue comes up when the XSLT result type is created because in the exposed set of members exists some JPA methods which can not be serialised, this is an issue with the JSON result type.

Comment: You need to also turn up logging to DEBUG level and set devMode on to see if there are any exceptions in the logs. If it's a lazy collection and you're not using an OSiV filter/interceptor you'll get a lazy load exception as soon as you try to access the collection.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments! Debug logging did not produce the actual error, but debugging through Eclipse revealed that it was, indeed, a problem with the lazy parameters. The problem is that, even if I load those with a join they are connected to other tables via lazy parameters (this time generating a "Cannot access bean property" error and going into an endless loop), and before you know it I'm loading the whole database, which I do not want to do. I have not heard of OSiV, so I will look into it and see if I can use it somehow (I am using the filter from Struts instead of Hibernate).

Comment: Quaternion, you said, "Just because the association is lazy does not mean that it should not be fetched before going to the view," but if that is so, then what is the point of having a lazy association? The association is lazy because sometimes I want to grab it and sometimes I do not so, if I do not grab it, how do I extract the available data out of the Hibernate object with triggering the LazyInitializationException? If you have to grab the data every time, does that not defeat the purpose of a lazy collection?